# Copy from workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple workbooks in a folder #1 and I'm trying to copy certain cells information from one worbook to another.

The source files in the folder are .xslm and named "1" "2" "3".... etc

The target files (which I'm trying to copy the cells to) are in another folder are .csv and named "1" "2" "3".... etc

I have about 1000 files that I'm trying information from. so copying them one by one will take me forever

[Source File Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFTR1.jpg)

[Target File Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCLa3.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a list of filenames to read from and another list of files to write to?

Comment: folder1 that contains the source fileshas 30 files. the first file named 1.xlsm. the second is 2.xlsm. the third files is 3.xlsm and so on so forth.

Comment: The same thing or the destination folder which contains the target files are named: 1.csv. 2.csv, 3.csv...etc. so I want the information to go from the source to the target files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files you want to copy from are in a folder `C:\MyExcelFiles\` and assuming they are named `1.xlsm`, `2.xlsm` and the output files should be `1.xls` and `2.xls`, then it is a straight forward thing to do:

```
Sub CopyMacro()
    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim SourceFileName As String
    Dim DestinationFileName As String
    
    Dim SourceWorkbook As String
    Dim DestinationWorkbook As String
    
    
    SourceFolder = "C:\MyExcelFiles\"
    
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False  ' avoid security warning
    For I = 1 To 100
        SourceFileName = SourceFolder & I & ".xlsm"
        DestinationFileName = SourceFolder & I & ".xls"   ' could be any other file
        
        On Error Resume Next
        
        Workbooks.Open SourceFileName, ReadOnly:=True
        
        If Err > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Could not open file :" & SourceFileName
            Exit Sub
        End If
        SourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        
       
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate   ' assuming the data you want to copy is on the first sheet
        Range("a1:d6").Copy
        
        Workbooks.Add
        DestinationWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        
        Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Workbooks(DestinationWorkbook).SaveAs DestinationFileName
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        
        
        Workbooks(SourceWorkbook).Close
        
        DoEvents  ' give a chance for mouse events and keyboard events to get executed
                  ' this will also allow you to press CTRL+PAUSE if you want to stop the macro
        
        
        
    Next
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True   'Switch alerts back on
    
End Sub
```

Please keep in mind, I did not test the code. But I am sure you will be able to fix it if it has any bugs, or errors.

Comment: Thank you so much. I get a message saying "the file format and extension of don't match the file could be corrupted or unsafe

Comment: The source file should be .csv not .xls. and when I open the file it's empty and there is nothing bein copied